# Create array from EE image after reducing image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, landsat, numpy

I'm trying to create an array from an EE image, following the accepted answer in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350771/earth-engine-simplest-way-to-move-from-ee-image-to-array-for-use-in-sklearn/351177#351177). However, instead of grabbing a specific image, I start with an EE imageCollection, then reduce it to an image (taking the median across cloud free pixels). When grabbing a specific image, I get the expected shape of the np array; however, I'm not able to get the expected shape when starting with an imageCollection.

(This is a similar issue as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547601/imagecollection-reduce-functions-producing-single-pixel-image-when-exported-us), although I'm not sure of the solution in this context. In addition, [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285779/use-google-earth-engine-to-read-modis-ndvi-into-python) gets close to what I'm looking for -- but returns a 1d array, not a 2d array).

```py
#### Set up
import ee
import numpy as np
import geetools
from geetools import ui, cloud_mask

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

#### Create AOI
aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.8, 44.7],
    [-110.8, 44.6],
    [-110.6, 44.6],
    [-110.6, 44.7]]], None, False)

#### Create np array, starting from image
# This works!

img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_038029_20180810') 

band_arrs = img.sampleRectangle(region=aoi)
band_arr_b1 = band_arrs.get('B1')
np_arr_b1 = np.array(band_arr_b1.getInfo())
np_arr_b1.shape

# Returns --> (373, 531)


#### Create np array, starting from imageCollection
# This doesn't seem to work

mask_l8SR_all = cloud_mask.landsatSR()

img = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')\
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2020-12-31')\
  .map(mask_l8SR_all)\
  .median()\
  .multiply(0.0001)

band_arrs = img.sampleRectangle(region=aoi)
band_arr_b1 = band_arrs.get('B1')
np_arr_b1 = np.array(band_arr_b1.getInfo())
np_arr_b1.shape

# Returns --> (1, 1)
```

[Google Colab link to the above code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XT3oLKD7bWIlMH59ME7S4TBUSOmBBOjS?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

SampleRectangle samples in the projection of the image; composites don't have a projection.  Assign one with setDefaultProjection.

```
collection = (ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2020-12-31')
  .map(mask_l8SR_all))
img = (collection.median()
  .multiply(0.0001)
  .setDefaultProjection(collection.first().projection()))
```